# Error while trying to display content from a store

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am trying to display `console.log(r.get('info'))` but, i am getting the output as `(an empty string)`. What might have caused this error ?

```
var myst = Ext.getStore('MyStore');    
var r = myst.getAt(0);
myst.on('load', function() {
    r = myst.getAt(0);
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.get('info'));
});


UPDATE 1
```

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [

        {
            name: 'info'
        }
    ]
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I actually get `Object { phantom=true, internalId="ext-record-18", raw={...}, more...}` when i print `console.log(r)'`and inside raw, i see `info:"myname"`.

Comment: Please post the response from the server. It is likely that the returned data does not include an `info` field or it is misspelled. Also what does the `MyStore` model look like?

Comment: I have added the Model of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display array or objects try console.dir(object).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your suggestion helped me to get more information about the error. It was in the Store.